# How to select last records of each value using Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

How to select latest of each option_id of a user_id?

```
+-----+-----------+---------+-------+
| id  | option_id | user_id | value |
+-----+-----------+---------+-------+
| 241 |         6 |       2 |     2 |
| 240 |         5 |       2 |     1 |
|  90 |         5 |       2 |    15 |
|  75 |         4 |       2 |    11 |
|  76 |         4 |       2 |     1 |
|  77 |         4 |       2 |     2 |
|  72 |         4 |       1 |    10 |
|  71 |         4 |       1 |    15 |
|  70 |         5 |       1 |     2 |
+-----+-----------+---------+-------+
```

How to write a query using Eloquent to achieve only the latest of each option_id of a given user_id?

For the table provided, the output for user_id 2 should be records id:
241,240,75.

For user_id 1 records:
72, 70

EDIT:

Just to re-iterate, I would like to return a collection of latest option_id for a given user_id.

Therefore  for user_id 2, there would be 3 records:

- record id 241 which holds the latest value for option_id 6
- record id 240 which holds the latest value for option_id 5
- record id 75 which holds the latest value for option_id 4

For user_id 1 there would be 2 records only:

- record id 72 which holds the latest value for option_id 4
- record id 70 which holds the latest value for option_id 5

Comment: Can you explain what you're asking? The last record for user_id 2 is id 76. It's not clear what you're wanting to select.

Comment: What model is this?

Comment: @MrMoxy User 2 has entries for option_id 4, 5 and 6. And he basically needs the newest entry for each option_id.

Comment: @Thomas that is exactly what I want. Thanks

Comment: Table::select(DB::raw('max(created_at)'),'col1,col2,col3'))->groupby('option_id')->distinct()->latest()->get(); ? Try This?

Comment: @LimKeanPhang sorry, no good, havent got created_at column to go by. It would be the highest id to use to decide about newest option_id.

Comment: Table::select(DB::raw('max(id)'),'col1,col2,col3'))->groupby('option_id')->distinct()->latest()->get(); //Max id perhaps ? According to you statement above

Comment: But 77 is the "latest" option value for user_id 2, option_id 4. MySQL cannot select based on position or order of entry into the table, only based on values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was as easy as:

```
      $options= DB::table('options')
            ->where('user_id', Auth::getUser()->id)
            ->groupBy("option_id")
            ->orderBy("option_id", "DESC")
            ->get();
```

But had to set strict mode to false for this query and put it back to true, once data retrieved.

Before the query:

```
        // turn off strict mode for the below query
        config()->set('database.connections.mysql.strict', false);
        \DB::reconnect(); //important as the existing connection if any would be in strict mode
```

and after the query:

```
        //now changing back the strict ON
        config()->set('database.connections.mysql.strict', true);
        \DB::reconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the table is User, and considering that `$id` is dynamic. Maybe this one you mean:

```
$user = User::where('user_id', $id) 
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC') 
            ->get();
```

And lastly use this code `$user->unique('option_id')` to get the actual result.

---

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi, this selected the latest id, not the latest id of  each option_id.

Comment: @JDoe do you mean get the latest record basing option_id? I made an edit, could you check.

Comment: I am afraid this is not what I wanted. I added some description to my question. Basically I want to return the highest (latest / newest) of each option_id (just one record) for a user_id 2 for example. Considering there are 6 option_ids, I would expect 6 records to be returned with latest values only.

Comment: @JDoe could you try my edited code. I think that will works

Comment: thanks, but no good, your solution returns collection of all option_ids not the latest only.

Comment: @JDoe bro can you try the updated post. and let me know the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is called user_options, here is the Eloquent query to select the records you are looking for.

```
        $getValues = DB::table('user_options')
        ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT max(user_options.id) FROM user_options INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT option_id, user_id FROM user_options GROUP BY option_id, user_id) sets
                        WHERE user_options.option_id = sets.option_id AND user_options.user_id = sets.user_id
                        GROUP BY user_options.option_id, user_options.user_id
            ) valuerecords'),
        function($join)
        {
           $join->on('user_options.id', '=', 'valuerecords.id');
        })->select(
            'id',
            'option_id',
            'user_id',
            'value'
        )->get();
```

The raw select query gets the ids of the latest records, and then this is joined back to the table to grab the records.

Please note that the "latest" record is the one with the highest id, so it will grab record 77 not 75. If you're defining latest differently, you can change the raw query accordingly.